# How can I connect a godaddy site on shared hosting to use a mongodb db on amazon ec2?

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, asp.net-mvc-4, amazon-ec2

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 site on godaddy shared hosting and it uses mongodb for its storage for our reporting system and I have implemented a MongoDB Membership provider for authentication.  I have set up the mongodb instance with an elastic IP.  The instance is on Win 2k12 for the moment, with MongoDB running as a windows service.  Locally, I can see it, ping it, use it while debugging my app, connect MongoVUE to it and even remote desktop into it.

However, when I deployed our site to godaddy and try to register a user, which has the MongoDB Membership provider trying to save it into the database, I basically get a connection timeout error.  I've pasted the error at the bottom.

Things I've tried:
1. looking up the godaddy site's ip and opening all tcp ports in the amazon security group for traffic coming from that ip
2. opening up all tcp ports for all traffic from all addresses
3. turning off the windows firewall on the mongodb server
4. 2 and 3 together

I'm wondering if maybe the mvc site can't get out of the godaddy network in order to get to the amazon ec2 instance.  So maybe its more of an issue of godaddy blocking it than amazon?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!!

Error message:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond (my ip):27017

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond (my ip):27017

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x274c): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond (my ip):27017]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +208
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP) +120
   System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP) +70
   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.Open() +158
   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(BsonBuffer buffer, Int32 requestId) +196
   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage message) +125
   MongoDB.Driver.Operations.CommandOperation`1.Execute(MongoConnection connection) +193
   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.RunCommandAs(MongoConnection connection, String databaseName, IMongoCommand command) +189
   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Ping(MongoConnection connection) +331
   MongoDB.Driver.MongoServerInstance.Connect() +371
   MongoDB.Driver.Internal.DirectMongoServerProxy.Connect(TimeSpan timeout, ReadPreference readPreference) +222
```

Comment: Can you check your command line options for MongoDB for a [`bind_ip`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp) value? FYI, you can check this in the `mongo` shell with `db.serverCmdLineOpts()`. If you've installed a recent version of MongoDB it is probably only listening to localhost (127.0.0.1). I would also try connecting via command-line from your GoDaddy instance to AWS to confirm there are no firewalls blocking access to the MongoDB port ([default: 27017](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/)).

Comment: Stennie, I can connect fine from my machine, so I don't think that's necessary for local, but that's a good connection testing tip to know.  As for GoDaddy, its shared hosting, so I don't have access to a command line on their end.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just heard back from GoDaddy that they intentionally block access to external resources/ip's for their shared hosting accounts. What crap! They're intentionally making their product less useful to their customer to try and force them to pay for a more expensive tier of hosting. If anyone knows of a good shared hosting provider for Windows/.NET that doesn't do stuff like this, I'm all ears! Thanks!